# NullPointerException, integration test ejb

Tags: java, maven, junit, mockito, dbunit

I have a web services with too many method, before now I "test it" manually with soap, but now I want to do that with Junit and other framework to interact with database and use @EJB annotation.
The first example that I found, was to use DBunit and so I connected to the database and put a row into a table(and it works). But when I try to reuse this connection, and try to directly invoke my @Stateless method I have too many Error such NullPointer exception on the EJB or on the entity manager, so I tried a complet different logic and use Mockito, like this:

```
public class ReportBeanTest {

    //This is my Stateless class
    private ReportFc reportBean = new ReportFc();

    @Before
    public void injectMockEntityManager() throws Exception {
        EntityManager entityManager = mock(EntityManager.class);
        reportBean.emReport = entityManager;
        DateFc dateF= mock(DateFc.class);
        reportBean.dateF =dateF;
        QuerysFc queryF= mock(QuerysFc .class);
        reportBean.queryF =queryF;
        reportBean.getReport("myReportA", new Date(), new Date());
    }
}
```

And here my ReportFc.java :

```
    @Stateless
    public class ReportFc {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="myDb")
        public
        EntityManager emReport;
        @EJB
        public
        DateFc dateF;

        @EJB
        public
        QuerysFc queryF;

        public List<MyList> getReport(String myReport,
                Date from_date,
                Date to_date
                ) throws WSException {
            try{
                List<WsMap_v3> resultList = new LinkedList<WsMap_v3>();

                Date start= dataF.parserDateFormat(from_date,0,"noTime");
                Date end= dataF.parserDateFormat(to_date,0,"noTime");
                dateF.verifyTimeInterval(start,end);
                Query qC=queryF.queryGetReportBetweenDate(start, end, myReportA);
...///
    }
```

I have see that every variable that use external EJB is null, as in my case : 
Date start, Date end, Query qC an so on.... What I am doing wrong? there is other way to test this function that use EJB or entitymanager? 
I am using maven so if there is other framework to use I have no problem to import it.
Other thing: all my bean of my db are in jar that I import with maven dependecy

Comment: I think it's worth to take a look here: http://arquillian.org/ Apart from that if you are writing integration tests you should take a look at maven-failsafe-plugin and name the test accordingly like `*IT.java` ...which is the default for maven-failsafe-plugin..

Comment: @khmarbaise can you please link me an example of integration test with maven-failsafe-plugin ?